# Как использовать локальную переменную из одного метода в другом

Tags: c#

Как использовать локальную переменную из одного метода в другом.

P.S. Сделать эту переменную полем класса нельзя по заданию

```
using System;
using static System.Math;
    
class Triangle
{
    private double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    public Triangle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите координаты вершин треугольника.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите координаты 1-ой вершины:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("x1 = ");
        x1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("y1 = ");
        y1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите координаты 2-ой вершины:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("x2 = ");
        x2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("y2 = ");
        y2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите координаты 3-ей вершины");
        Console.WriteLine("x3 = ");
        x3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("y3 = ");
        y3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public double SideLength()
    {
        double A, B, C;
        A = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2.0));
        B = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x3 - x2, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y2 - y3, 2.0));
        C = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x3, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y1 - y3, 2.0));
    }
    public double Perimetr(ref double A1, ref double B1, ref double C1)
    {
        double A=A1, B=B1, C=C1;
        return (A + B + C);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут скорее имелось в виду что-то такое, можно использовать кортежи, если это современный `C#`:

```cs
    public (double A, out double B, out double C) SideLength(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
    {
        A = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2.0));
        B = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x3 - x2, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y2 - y3, 2.0));
        C = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x3, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y1 - y3, 2.0));
        return (A, B, C)
    }

    public double Perimetr(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
    {
        (double A, out double B, out double C) = SideLength(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
        return (A + B + C);
    }
```

Ну то есть в любом случае вам нужно будет в явном виде как-то вернуть переменные из функции и принять их в вызывающей функции. Можно сделать и через `out`, но, наверное, кортежи удобнее/понятнее всё-таки.

Answer (score 0):

Надо передать данные в метод точно так же, как это сделано в `Perimetr`,  только не обязательно делать их `ref`

Ну и в таком случае объявление их в начале класса в виде `private double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;`  уже не имеет смысла. Надо будет их объявлять в конструкторе `Triangle`

Comment: Но `private double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;` это же поля класса, а мне нужно использовать вычисленные значения A, B и С в другом методе

Comment: Ну так вызови метод в нутри другого и передай туда данные